# code simplification and concatenation

Tags: java

When asked to answer the following question: Assume that the share points of a company fluctuate with a particular pattern in the New York Stock
Exchange. It increases by 50 points every day in the first half of a given period and decreases by 25
points in the second half. If the number of days in a given period is odd, the first half is considered a
day more than the second half.
Write a Java program that will first ask users to enter the number of days in a given period and the
share points on the first day. The number of days that is entered must not be less than 10 and more
than 20. If it is not so, the user must be prompted to enter the input again with the following message:
“The number of days doesn’t meet the required criteria, enter it again”. The program should output
a table showing the days and the share points on those days.

I wrote the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionOne
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int numberofDays;

        int sharePoints;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");

        numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Share points on the first day: ");

        sharePoints = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(numberofDays < 10 || numberofDays > 20)
        {
            System.out.println("The number of days doesn’t meet the required criteria, enter it again");
           // needs to loop to beginning to make program carry out proper function//
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Day " + " Share Points");

            switch(numberofDays)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 25);

                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 75);

                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 75);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints  + 50);

                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 75);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);

                  break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 125);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(6 + "    " + sharePoints + 75);

                    break;

                case 7:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 175);
                    System.out.println(6 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(7 + "    " + sharePoints + 125);

                    break;

                case 8:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 175);
                    System.out.println(6 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(7 + "    " + sharePoints + 125);
                    System.out.println(8 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);

                    break;

                case 9:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "    " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(7 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(8 + "    " + sharePoints + 175);
                    System.out.println(9 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);

                    break;

                case 10:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "    " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(7 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(8 + "    " + sharePoints + 175);
                    System.out.println(9 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(10 + "   " + sharePoints + 125);

                    break;

                case 11:
                    System.out.println(1 + "    " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "    " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "    " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "    " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "    " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "    " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "    " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(8 + "    " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(9 + "    " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(10 + "   " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(11 + "   " + sharePoints + 175);          

                    break;

                case 12:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 175);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);                  

                    break;

                case 13:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);

                    break;

                case 14:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 175);

                    break;

                case 15:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(15 + "  " + sharePoints + 225);

                    break;

                case 16:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(15 + "  " + sharePoints + 225);
                    System.out.println(16 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);

                    break;

                case 17:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 450);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 425);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(15 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(16 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(17 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);

                    break;

                case 18:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 450);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 425);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(15 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(16 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(17 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(18 + "  " + sharePoints + 225);

                    break;

                case 19:
                    System.out.println(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 450);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 500);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 475);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 450);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 425);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(15 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(16 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(17 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(18 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(19 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);

                    break;

                case 20:
                    System.out.print(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);
                    System.out.println(2 + "  " + sharePoints + 100);
                    System.out.println(3 + "  " + sharePoints + 150);
                    System.out.println(4 + "  " + sharePoints + 200);
                    System.out.println(5 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);
                    System.out.println(6 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(7 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(8 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(9 + "  " + sharePoints + 450);
                    System.out.println(10 + "  " + sharePoints + 500);
                    System.out.println(11 + "  " + sharePoints + 475);
                    System.out.println(12 + "  " + sharePoints + 450);
                    System.out.println(13 + "  " + sharePoints + 425);
                    System.out.println(14 + "  " + sharePoints + 400);
                    System.out.println(15 + "  " + sharePoints + 375);
                    System.out.println(16 + "  " + sharePoints + 350);
                    System.out.println(17 + "  " + sharePoints + 325);
                    System.out.println(18 + "  " + sharePoints + 300);
                    System.out.println(19 + "  " + sharePoints + 275);
                    System.out.println(20 + "  " + sharePoints + 250);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I encountered one large problem and two smaller ones; the first of the smaller problems was that my answers are coming out as the entered number plus the number I wanted to add (so if you enter 100, and it adds 25, you should get 125- however I get 10025). The second small problem is that I want to loop the code where I have annotated it in the code so that it returns to the beginning- but I do not know how to do that. Lastly, my biggest problem is that I want to simplify this code using loop statements, but have yet been unable to successfully do so. Really the last part is a stretch, if I can get help on the concatenation issue and looping issue then I should be O.K. and would be eternally grateful. Just my code will be much more difficult to troubleshoot and to read.

Comment: Try grouping things, e.g `System.out.println(1 + "    " + (sharePoints + 50));`  to make sure that the addition takes place before the string concatenation .

Comment: try code reuse and extracting in methods. it'll make this entire code a lot more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you try to add a string with a number, Java will first change the number to string and then concat them all. Hence you get `"1  10025"` for the line `System.out.print(1 + "  " + sharePoints + 50);`.

   Therefore, you need to change it to

   ```
   System.out.print(1 + " " + (sharePoints + 50));
   ```

   Then it will first calculate the maths and then change it to String for concat.
2. To loop for something while true, e.g., users input, you may use the following code segment.

   ```
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");
   numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();
   while (numberofDays < 10 || numberofDays > 20)
   {
       System.out.println("The number of days doesn’t meet the required criteria, enter it again");
       System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");
       numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();
   }
   ```

   It will ask the user to input again when days less than 10 and more than 20.
3. To use loop to calculate the sharePoints in different days, you may add it using loop on the fly. Add 50 to sharePoints in each iteration for the first half of days and minus 25 to sharePoints for another half of days, like this.

   ```
   int increaseDays = (int) (numberofDays + 0.5) / 2;

   int i;
   for (i = 1; i <= increaseDays; i++) 
   {
       sharePoints += 50;
       System.out.println(i + "  " + sharePoints);
   }

   for (; i <= numberofDays; i++)
   {
       sharePoints -= 25;
       System.out.println(i + "  " + sharePoints);
   }
   ```

Comment: `int increaseDays = (numberofDays + 0.5) / 2;`
That will throw incompatible types error.
Also scope of **i** is limited to the first loop. You would need to declare i outside the loops.

Comment: @searcotjabali, you are right, I haven't tested it. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different code from Alex.
The user input loop and the arithmetic evaluation issues were resolved by him
Here is the loop to calculate the share points.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numberofDays; i++)
{
    if(numberofDays % 2 == 0) 
        if(i <= numberofDays/2) {
            sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
            System.out.println("Day : " + i + " : Share Points : " + sharePoints);
        }
        else {
            sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
            System.out.println("Day : " + i + " : Share Points : " + sharePoints);
}
else {
    if(i <= numberofDays/2 + 1) {
        sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
        System.out.println("Day : " + i + " : Share Points : " + sharePoints);
    }
    else {
    sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
    System.out.println("Day : " + i + " : Share Points : " + sharePoints);
}
}
}
```

Comment: since I am using a hybrid form of the two codes you guys provided to me; I'd like to ask how I would get the first number (using your code formatting) as itself. For example, if I enter 11 as the day, and 550 as the initial share price; the code gives me 600 as my first number, when I want 550 as my first number, then 600, and so forth.

Comment: You may use an array to store the outcome, like `arr[i-1] = sharePoints` after the calculation of each day.

Comment: @ProfessorDoctorDickButt: Simply switch the +50 & -25 statements with the Print statements. Then it will print the value and later increment

Answer (score 0):

Ideal scenario to use java 8 streams and lambda.